# Why was this question about MATLAB unit testing and Jenkins closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I posted this question some time ago: [Why is Jenkins counting test case failures incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234734/why-is-jenkins-counting-test-case-failures-incorrectly).

It was put on hold as off topic. I didn't understand why, so I re-wrote the whole question and added a screenshot to make it as clear as possible. I also tried to ask in the comments for explanation as to why the question would be off topic. In the end, the question was closed without any explanation.

I think the question is specific, well-defined and programming related. Stack Overflow doesn't appear very welcoming to new/occasional users if their question are easily rejected without good explanation.

Would somebody like to tell me what's really wrong with the question?

Comment: *"In the end, the question was closed without any explanation."* No, it wasn't. Read the detailed close reason given in the big yellow box appearing underneath the question.

Comment: I also don't understand why it is closed for that specific reason. That said, maybe that question is too specific to test, build and deployment operations that it might also fly on [devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help) or maybe even [qa.se](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @CodyGray, sure I saw the box. But I don't understand. The problem statement is clear I think. But reproducing the issue in the question doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: @Lauri Why can't you create a testcase that one can run in Jenkins to recreate the issue?

Comment: I pinged three of the close voters to make them aware of this post and asked them to chime in.

Comment: Not my close vote, but I concur: the only information in the question is a screen shot and an allegation that the information in that screen shot is incorrect. You are apparently speculating that this is a well-known quirk and that somebody who knows Jenkins is aware of it and can tell you how to resolve the problem; but if that turns out to be false, we really only have your say-so to rely on. At least some log excerpts or other information to persuade us that the screen shot is incorrect would be useful IMNSHO.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I ran the same test case in a completely new Jenkins that I have set up. The issue did not re-appear. However, for future needs it would be good to know what was wrong in the initial setup. But even more interesting here is to learn to ask things in a correct way so that the questions don't get rejected.

Comment: Nobody's going to be able to tell you what's wrong with the initial setup as you can't tell us what you did. The close reason has a link that provides guidance on asking questions in a correct way.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Many questions get answered without being reproducible. Here is another question from me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742522/using-jenkins-include-regions-feature-why-is-workspace-not-visible. I wonder why this wasn't put on hold. Instead I received help from someone who new it's a Jenkins bug.

Comment: @Lauri Not all questions that should be closed **are** closed. Since the site is community moderated, it depends on the right users getting to the post and using their votes; so there is a bit of luck involved.

Comment: If you give us a list of all your questions that should be closed, we’ll be happy to oblige. :-) In all seriousness, what @yivi said. Each question is best judged in isolation, because the volume of questions on this site means some are inevitably missed. The issue here, as noted in the close reason, is lack of repro code. Good questions have a test case that demonstrates the problem. If that’s not feasible, or unnecessary (be careful with this!), you *at least* need to provide as much context/details as possible. This site demands authoritative answers. Guessing doesn’t work.

Answer (score 13):

I am one of the users who voted to close that question.

Why?

Because you must provide enough information on the question itself to recreate that problem. Guessing your problem and hoping for an answer is not the way how the site works.

Your remaining option is to edit your question and add enough information to reproduce that problem. Your edit will push question to reopen queue, where community members review your edit and may cast vote to reopen.

Believe me, all community members who have domain knowledge about your problem are willing to help.

Comment: I already got rid of the original problem with a completely new Jenkins. More interesting for me was why the question was rejected. As I said in one of the comments above, many questions get and can be answered without being reproducible. Like  these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289920/using-gpu-with-matlab and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742522/using-jenkins-include-regions-feature-why-is-workspace-not-visible. Would you have put these as off-topic too?

Comment: You already get answer from yivi comment.

Comment: @Lauri I'd have closed the GPU one. There's too little information in the question to tell us where the problem is (You have a GPU, MATLAB doesn't recognise it, nothing more), and especially your self-answer just says 'Oops, I had an old video driver', which would fall under the category "Off-topic: Not reproducible or a simple typo. Resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." as updating video drivers is a fairly common thing to do, and does not follow logically from the question at all, as in: only you, with the additional info that the driver was old, could've solved this.

Comment: Shree, note that editing the question has already been done by the OP, so any further edits will not push it into the queue again AFAIK.

Comment: @Adriaan Closing questions because they don't contain enough information? Often it is very difficult to know what information is actually the critical one. Wouldn't it be more fruitful to ask more information rather than just close a question? This is what ZizyArcher did and that was actually enough to solve the GPU issue. Updating the driver did indeed follow logically: running 'gpuDevice' on Matlab recommended to do so.

Comment: @Lauri yes, questions lacking enough information *should* be closed. Note that closed is **not** the same as deleted; you get the chance to edit the question, after which it will be submitted to the reopen queue, so if you add enough information for the question to be answerable, it gets reopened. This is a mechanism put in place to force people to change their questions, as opposed to leaving them answerable an open to all kinds of guessing answers. So yes, please do edit after a question is closed and it will be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 11):

I was one of the people who voted to close your initial question. I'll copy it here and try to comment on the issues I see.

> I'm using Matlab unit test framework and Jenkins running on Linux to execute test cases.

Good start, we know what you are using. Although it's not clear to me what the "MATLAB unit test framework" is, it's probably a built-in toolbox.

> One of my tests has been failing for the past 5-6 builds but for some reason Jenkins says 'Failing for the past 1 build', for every build that failed.

What test? You didn't mention one in any of the rest of the text. It's very difficult to see where the problem is without you telling us what's going on. Hence the close reason: we need an MCVE.

> Moreover, the 'Age' link in Jenkins' test result section always points to the latest build, not the one where the failure first appeared. What could be the reason for this?

Additional information on the error, good, but still it is unclear what build or what test failed in the first place.

---

Even with the updated question (which I hadn't seen until now), this problem persists. I see a screenshot and a question 'How can this happen'. Well, probably for a lot of reasons (I don't know Jenkins, so this might actually be not true). The thing which would help us to determine the issue is, again, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can recreate the issue you are facing, making it possible for us to actually debug.

In [a comment on Shree's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381866/why-was-this-question-about-matlab-unit-testing-and-jenkins-closed#comment681890_381868) you say "I already got rid of the original problem with a completely new Jenkins." Which means that your issue is now *No longer reproducible*. It wasn't in the first place for us, due to lacking information, and now not even for you because you changed versions and the problem is gone. It could've been a bug in your test, in Jenkins, in some driver you installed, perhaps even [Tim lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/288240#288240). It's impossible for anyone now to say what the problem is.

Reading the comments make me think you actually want more general advice on how to ask questions, therefore I'd like to suggest [the help centre summary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as *[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)*, a blog post by the top user, in terms of reputation points, on the site.